# What is the best way of logging save/delete method in JPARepository (Hibernate, Spring)

Tags: spring, hibernate, logging, repository, aspect

I need to logging all save/delete methods in JPARepository. I need to save in logs who did it, what method (save or delete) and when dit it.

Yes, I can put manually in each method save/delete of JPARepository methods of logService. But maybe anybody know another way how to do it automatically (maybe using annotations).

**UPDATED:**
I'm trying to write logs using aspects.  I've added to my WebConfig:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

and created LogAspect:

```
@Aspect
public class LogAspect {

    @Before("com.springapp.mvc.repositories")
    public void writeLog(){
        System.out.println("write log");
    }

}
```

Added dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

but when I call repository methods, message "write log" not appears in console.

**UPDATED**

Ok, I solved my problems by several steps:

1. Upgraded spring to version `4.2.1.RELEASE`
2. Added `@Component` to `LogAspect`
3. Changed `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`
4. Changed `@Before("execution(* com.springapp.mvc.repositories.*.*(*)))")`

**LAST QUESTION:** in my logs I need to know which repository (UserRepository, ImageRepository or else) was called and which method (save or delete). First * after com.springapp.mvc.repositories is which repository was called, and second which method.  Is it possible to retrive it inside method?

Comment: Hibernate envers can do the auditing joined with the [Spring Data JPA Auditing support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing) and you're set.

Comment: i updated my question, now i'm trying to write logs using aspects, but aspect not calling.

Comment: Your point cut is wrong, but I would suggest using what I suggested instead of trying to implement your own.

Comment: thanks for this link, in next project i will use it for sure. But I already created LogRepository. please, advice me, how to write aspect  correctly.  thanks

Comment: Adding Spring Data JPA is as easy as removing your implementation and replace `LogRepository` with an interface and be done. Using Envers has nothing to do with Spring Data and you can just add Hibernate Envers and you have it working. Your point cut is wrong because it isn't a valid point cut should be something like `@Before(execution com.springapp.mvc.repositories..*.*(..))`.

Comment: thanks, that work. Just last step I need to solve in my updated question

Comment: I suggest a read on AOP and the fact that you can use a `JoinPoint` as method argument..

Comment: thanks, everything works